# compile qt 5.12.4 with open ssl static fail

Tags: qt, compilation, static, openssl

I am trying to compile qt with open ssl statically

I could compile openssl using vs2017 after install perl and configuring it
i used nmake and it worked with -no-shared smoothly.
Then i open the openssl folder and have the following
dll->x64->release>
    bin
         ->c_rehash.pl
         ->libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
         ->libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
         ->libssl-1_1-x64.dll
         ->libssl-1_1-x64.pdb
         ->openssl.exe
         ->openssl.pdb
    include
           openssl
                   header files
    lib  ->libcrypto.lib
         ->libssl.lib
         ->ossl_static.pdb
         - engines-1_1 -> capi.dll
                          capi.pdb
                          padlock.dll
                          padlock.pdb

Then i opened VS command line
and opened Qt 5.12.4 coder

configure -static -openssl-linked -opengl dynamic -nomake tests -nomake examples -I "T:\openssl\dll\x64\release\include" -L "T:\openssl\dll\x64\release\lib" OPENSSL_LIBS="-lUser32 -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32"

I get the following:
error feature 'openssl-linked' was enabled but the pre-condition !features.securetransport && libs.openssl' failed